# How to properly import and test a function(s) within a named export react functional component?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

My app was created with create-react-app so should be ready to use with jest.  I am trying to run a test on functions within a functional component.  When running 'npm test', the test fails displaying

```
    TypeError: chatlist.randoColor is not a function
```

I've tried exporting as default and import as the following:

```
    import { Chatlist } from '../Components/ChatList';
    const randoColor = require('../Components/ChatList');
    import randoColor from '../Components/ChatList';
```

however, all seem to not recognize any functions found within the component.  Ideally, I would like to keep it as a named export but open to all suggestions.  For a function like this it is also suggested in its own utility file possibly, however there are other functions I have within the component I would like to import and test as well without storing all the functions in a utility file.

Here is my project directory structure.

```
src
| __tests__
  | ChatList.test.js
| Components
  | ChatList.js
```

I would like to write a test for a function (or any function really) found within my ChatList component, randoColor.

```
export const ChatList = ({ chats }) => {
  const randoColor = max => Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
   if (chats.length > 0) {
    return <main></main
}
```

This is my ChatList.test.js file.

```
import * as chatlist from '../Components/ChatList';

describe('<Chatlist />', () => {
  test('randoColor fn should generate a random number given a max input', () => {
    expect(chatlist.randoColor(230)).not.toBeNaN();
  });
});
```

Expected result is for the npm test to run successfully, detecting the function and pass.  Actual result is:
        TypeError: chatlist.randoColor is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`randoColor` lives only in the scope of the method `ChatList`, so it can't be accessed from the outside. Also it's better to access react components only thru the props.

Since the method doesn't use any of the ChatList props, I would recommend moving it outside of the method. Like:

```
const ChatList = ({ chats }) => { 
   if (chats.length > 0) {
       return <main></main
   }
}
ChatList.randoColor = max => Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max))
export default ChatList
```

And that can be accessed like:

```
import ChatList from '../Components/ChatList'
ChatList.randoColor(230)
```

I would recommend moving that function somewhere else like creating a utils folder and have like a utils/colorUtils.js with this method and others that are related to color. And that leaves the component `<ChatList />` more clean and the only way possible to change it is thru props or maybe Context.

Also I changed the `export ChatList` to `export default ChatList`, so that you can access it without the `{ }`

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering if there was any other way around it but it appears that having the function reside in its own util file is the way to go

Comment: Yeah, but hopefully more components start using that method and makes it worth the utils file. Good luck!